# PooledOLS under Linearmodels throwing zero division error

Tags: regression, panel, divide-by-zero

I am new to Python and trying to run a panel regression on the following dataset (dependent variable is COAS, while everything else except DATE is estimator). I referenced the [example](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/examples/examples.html) under Linearmodels module documentation for my code. I have made the dataframe a multiindex frame and changed DATE column to datetime object.

```
          DATE   EXD/FXR   INT/REV       3MOAS  EMCHNG     RXG  COAS  CTRY
0    1/31/2014  2.694349  0.142077  308.454243    47.2  -2.178   337  INDO
1    2/28/2014  2.662493  0.109509  310.799125    29.4  -4.103   273  INDO
2    3/31/2014  2.702085  0.116384  298.476564    -2.4  -4.499   267  INDO
3    4/30/2014  2.638563  0.104091  282.209195   -23.3  -5.214   267  INDO
4    5/31/2014  2.663104  0.100000  259.753537   -10.0  -5.291   232  INDO
..         ...       ...       ...         ...     ...     ...   ...   ...
70  11/30/2019  3.175515  0.159561  176.421866  -148.2  -1.746   186  INDO
71  12/31/2019  3.131713  0.140611  173.654835  -114.4  -3.033   155  INDO
72   1/31/2020  3.123129  0.216972  169.090508   -40.6  -1.440   181  INDO
73   2/29/2020  3.122425  0.158356  166.975114   -56.9   4.095   215  INDO
74   3/31/2020  3.217786  0.196329  216.335824   -76.4  17.883   357  INDO
```

Now when I run the below code

```
exog_vars = ['EXD/FXR','INT/REV','3MOAS','EMCHNG','RXG']
exog = sm.add_constant(data[exog_vars])
mod = PooledOLS(data.COAS, exog)
pooled_res = mod.fit()
print(pooled_res)
```

I get error below

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\linearmodels\panel\model.py in _rsquared(self, params, reweight)
498 
499         total_ss = float(w.T @ (e ** 2))
--> 500         r2b = 1 - residual_ss / total_ss
501 
502         #############################################

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

...which I traced back to PooledOLS source code and found it to be during the process of computing rsquared ([here](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/devel/_modules/linearmodels/panel/model.html)). Has anyone encountered similar problem at this stage? I found some less relevant posts saying this may be caused by data including negative values/zeros - I can confirm the data has no zeros but does have negative values, but can't see how this would matter.

Would greatly appreciate any help/thoughts/recommendations from the community. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer but here are some thoughts I had in your situation: Have you had a look at your `exog` variables? I assume that something went wrong there. Have you checked `data.dtypes` ? Might there be multicollinearity between Also, do I understand it correctly that you only have one entity, which you are observing over time?